# Cannot save thumbnail with Imagick

Tags: php, imagick

I'm trying to create a thumbnail of an image, however, I can display it just fine, but cannot save it.

For example:

```
$image = new Imagick("photo.png");
$image->thumbnailImage(100, 0);
header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $image;
```

This will in fact display my image in its thumbnailed form. But if I instead try to save it using `$image->writeImage("thumb_photo.png")` the script appears to stop (I confirmed this just by putting `echo Hello` or whatever afterwards) and no files have been created.

I'm using this on a server with Debian Wheezy, nginx, and PHP setup. The directory and PHP files themselves are readable, writable and have execute permissions for both the images and PHP files themselves. The imagick module version is 3.10. The PHP version is 5.4.

If someone can tell me what the problem could be I would appreciate it.

EDIT: After getting the exception, I am presented with `WriteBlob Failed "thumb_photo.png" @ error/png.c/MagickPNGErrorHandler/1728`.

Another thing, apparently if I change the output from "thumb_photo.png" to "photo.png" it works, but overwrites my image, how could I get around this and two why would it let me overwrite my image but not create a new one?

Comment: what happens if you try to save it using `$image->writeImage("/some/full/path/thumb_photo.png")`? Maybe it's not attempting to write to the directory you would expect

Comment: I tried that and it reports the same exception as before. I've tried multiple paths, none seem to work. However, if I change the path for the input file, to the full path, it actually reports that it cannot read the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently I had forgotten to change the group to `www-data` on the document root of the path to my files. I also needed to add `chmod -R g+s` to it as well. Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if www-data not existed, you can change ownership to apache:apache and will let me save to that folder. I'm using Centos 7, with standard php/mysql.